# what is the meaning of library icon in xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode

i'm confused with icon of library that presented in xcode 4.5. I did not know what different between these icons as these icons present for the same library. Sorry if this is a very basic question, but i cannot find any document that tell me what the difference of these icons.
I also posted the image of these icons. Thanks for any explanation.

[image: icon of lib looks like a new doc]

[image: icon of lib looks like a house]

[image: icon of lib looks like a square]

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, it appears that Xcode can find the file, but doesn't recognize it as a static library. The second one indicates that it is a static library. (It's supposed to be an icon of a Library where you'd check out books.) The third means that Xcode cannot find the file on disk. It may be pointing to the wrong path, for example.